# Is it legal to re-declare a member class after defining it?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, bimap, boost-bimap

I have a problem with compiling boost.bimap library. My test program is a blank main function and only one include directive(like `#include <boost/bimap.hpp>`). 
After some investigations I found out that preprocessor had made some interesting constructions from header file like:

```
struct A { struct B{}; struct B; };
```

I don't know if this is correct or not, but gcc accepts it while clang and icc don't. Who is right and what can I do to compile programs with bimap library? Unfortunately, I can't use gcc in this case.

Comment: Everything sounds to me like you've got errors somewhere else, and this is the result from the pre-processor standpoint.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Boost.Bimap. Just because you're using it in other parts of the code doesn't make it relevant to this.

Comment: What **exactly** is the error you are getting? (And why didn't you tell us it in the first place?)

Comment: invalid redeclaration of nested class
  BOOST_BIMAP_SYMMETRIC_METADATA_ACCESS_BUILDER this error I am getting

Comment: That's not **exactly** the error you are getting, because you left out the part that says `[-Werror,-Wredeclared-class-member]` **which is the important part**. That is what shows you are using -Werror, and can solve the problem by not doing that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, you are right, thank you for your attention. Problem was solved and we have nothing to do here

Answer (score 11):

`struct B{};` defines a nested class, then `struct B;` is a re-declaration of the same nested class.

GCC is wrong to accept the code ([bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67678)), because the standard says in [class.mem]:

> A member shall not be declared twice in the *member-specification*, except that a nested class or member class template can be declared and then later defined,

In your case the nested class is defined *then* declared, which is not allowed, so Clang and ICC are correct to give a diagnostic. However, when I test it they only give a warning, not an error, so maybe you are using `-Werror`, in which case stop doing that and the code should compile.

The problem in the Boost.Bimap code is a [known bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8743).

Comment: I linked to this answer from my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715610/is-a-forward-declaration-allowed-after-a-class-definition)