# Is a class declaration allowed after a class definition?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712057/is-this-trick-is-legal-and-why-compiler-made-it/32713932#32713932), and it completely puzzles me.

I was always thinking a class declaration can appear many times, and only the definition has to exist only once, like:

```
/*class Class {*/

    class A;         // (1) forward declaration

    class A {        // (2) definition, only once
       int m;
    };

    class A;         // (3) declaration again, legal?

    class A a;       // (4) declaration again, legal?

/*};*/
```

From the linked answer: (3) (and (4)?) is illegal if the code above is ***nested inside a class*** (definition and declarations of `class A` are nested inside `class Class`).

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class), I found an example of the above, ***not nested***:

> ```
> struct s { int a; };
> struct s; // does nothing (s already defined in this scope)
> void g() {
>     struct s; // forward declaration of a new, local struct "s"
>               // this hides global struct s until the end of this block
>     s* p;     // pointer to local struct s
>     struct s { char* p; }; // definitions of the local struct s
> }
> ```

See the second line.

**Question:** Given that it is illegal inside a class, is my example code, and the cppreference example above, legal when *not* nested inside a class? Or more generally: When can a class declaration follow a definition (how is it inside namespaces for example)? If it is legal, why is there a difference?

Comment: It simply becomes a declaration.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: The *forward* declaration becomes a declaration?

Comment: _Given that it is illegal inside a class, is my example code_ Says who?

Comment: @SimonKraemer, Jonathan Wakely, in the linked answer.

Comment: BTW: Forward declarations after the definition happens all the time e.g. dependend on the order you include the headers in a cpp.

Comment: I mean it looses the adverb `forward` and becomes a simple declaration.

Comment: Rules for classes are C++ only rules. A class is declared in one piece, and has no need for multiple forward declarations of the same item. Declarations outside classes mostly follow the less strict C rules, for compatibility.

Comment: @Barry, the part about namespaces, and the why. Bo Perssons comment answers the why a bit, but I still wonder why the rules have been made more strict, because it makes preprocessor-'generated' headers more error-prone, like in the linked question.

Comment: @101010 I removed 'forward' where not applicable, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [basic.def]:

> A declaration (Clause 7) may introduce one or more names into a translation unit **or redeclare names** introduced by previous declarations.

From [class.name]:

> A declaration consisting solely of *class-key identifier;* is either **a redeclaration of the name** in the current scope or a forward declaration of the identifier as a class name. It introduces the class name
>   into the current scope.

So it's generally legal to do this. There's just the one exception in [class.mem]:

> A member **shall not be declared twice** in the *member-specification*,
>   except that a nested class or member class template can be declared and then later defined, and except that an enumeration can be introduced with an *opaque-enum-declaration* and later redeclared with an *enum-specifier*.

Perfectly OK in namespace scope, not allowed in class scope.

---

As to why? Well, this rule let's you "forward" declare all the classes you need everywhere you would typically be allowed to do so:

```
// a.h
struct C;

struct A {
    C* c;
};

// b.h
struct C;

struct B {
    C& c;
};
```

without having to worry about somebody actually including the full declaration and breaking everything for you:

```
// d.h
#include "c.h"
#include "a.h" // now C was already declared!
#include "b.h" // and here too!

struct D { ... };
```

This isn't so much of a concern *within a class definition*. It can't exactly span multiple files. So the inability to redeclare nested types doesn't actually achieve anything.

Comment: Thanks, I think this pretty much nails it. And because there is no real advantage in allowing it inside classes, it's better to catch programmer errors by disallowing it?

Comment: It is explicit in quoted text, but not in your examples: **forward** declarations are legal even within a class definition.

Answer (score 2):

`class A;`  This is a forward declaration of incomplete `class A` (legal).

`class A {  int m; };` This is the definition of `Class A` (legal).

`class A;` This is re-declaration of `class A` (legal).

`class A a;` This is declaration of object `a` of type `A` (legal).

Comment: And inside namespaces?

Comment: @alain and inside namespace are also legal.